# Finding the number of scalene triangles

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Prove that the number of triangles with sides in integral centimetre and greatest side=$2m+1$cm is $(m+1)^2$.

My try:-
Let sides of triangle be $x,y,2m+1$

Case-1:- triangle is equilateral .

No. of triangles=1

Case-2:- triangle is isosceles and x=y

As $x+y>2m+1$ so $x>=m+1$. But $x<2m+1$
No. of triangles = $m$

Case-3:-triangle is isosceles and $x=2m+1$

$2(2m+1)>y$ and $y<2m+1$.
No. Of triangles =$2m$

Case-4:- scalene triangle

$x+y>2m+1$ and $x-y<2m+1$
I am unable to proceed further. Please help me

Comment: Are we looking for scalene triangles?

Comment: $2m+1 < x+y \leq 4m+2$. Thus $x+y = 2m+2, 2m+3,\ldots, 4m+2$. Now count the integer solutions to $x+y = k$ with $x, y \leq 2m+1$.

Answer (score 2):

The number of arbitrary, non-degenerated triangles with sides $1\le x\le y\le 2m+1$  in $\Bbb Z$ is computed as follows, where we split the counting w.r.t. $y$, the length of the side "on the second place", which must be at least $m+1$, and then we have a clear range for $x$, and now the computation in slow motion:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{1\le x\le y\le 2m+1}1
&=
\sum_{m+1\le y\le 2m+1}
\sum_{2m+2-y\le x\le y}1
\\
&=
\sum_{m+1\le y\le 2m+1}
(2y-(2m+2)+1)
\\
&=
\left(2\sum_{m+1\le y\le 2m+1}y\right)
-((2m+2)-1)(m+1)
\\
&=
\left(2\sum_{1\le y\le 2m+1}y\right)
-
\left(2\sum_{1\le y\le m}y\right)
-
(2m+1)(m+1)
\\
&=
(2m+1)(2m+2) - m(m+1) - (2m+1)(m+1)
\\
%&=
%2(2m+1)(m+1) - m(m+1) - (2m+1)(m+1)
%\\
&=
(m+1)\Big[ \ 4m+2 - m - 2m-1\ \Big]
\\
&=(m+1)^2\ .
\end{aligned}
$$